# Имитация гравитации в Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, математика, физика

Хотел сделать собственную гравитацию и по идее надо ускоренние свободного падения умножить на дельта тайм чтобы получить дельта ускорение и применить к позиции обьекта и вроде правильно так как за 1 секунду скорость равна ускорению через 2 сек в два раза больше и т.д, но почему-то обьект улетает с очень высокой скорости по сравнению с гравитаций RigidBody (сопротивление воздуха установлено на 0) и это проблема решается повторным умножением на дельту времени и "искусственная" гравитация работает так же как и у Rigidbody. Почему надо умножать 2 раза на дельта тайм я не могу понять.

"Неправильный" код в методе FixedUpdate:

```
velocity += Physics.gravity * Time.deltaTime;
Rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + velocity);
```

"Правильный" код в методе FixedUpdate:

```
velocity += Physics.gravity * Time.deltaTime * Time.deltaTime;
Rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position + velocity);
```

(На форуме впервые поэтому сильно не бейте пж)

Comment: что такое `Physics.gravity` и `Time.deltaTime`? Что конкретно в них хранится? Что хранится в переменной `velocity`?

Comment: @Grundy `Physics.gravity` - величина гравитации, `Time.deltaTime` - время, прошедшее с последнего кадра до текущего, `velocity`, судя по применению, текущая скорость объекта.

Comment: @KOTlK, какой тип переменных-то?

Comment: `gravity` - Vector3, `deltaTime` - float, `velocity` - Vector3.

Comment: Короче, никто не смог или не захотел ответь. Поэтому отвечу сам себе. При умножение gravity, а это вектор ускорение на дельту времени получаеться дельта ускорение и выходит что бы получить слейдущию позицию обьекта нужно скорость, которая равна ускорению за данную дельту времени, умножить тоже на дельта времени да бы получить пройденое расстояние

Comment: @KadiWhite01, для ответов есть отдельное поле. Если разобрался сам - добавь сам ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: @Grundy, понял, спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у нас есть:

1. Ускорение свободного падения (обозначим G) т.е векторная величина равная (0; 9.81; 0).
2. Текущая скорость, которая в моем случаем равна начальной т.е (0; 0; 0).
3. Дельта времени, ее для краткости будем называть dT (deltaTime), равная времени прошедшему с предыдущего вызова Update (Можно так же сказать кадра, думаю сейчас это не критично).

Формула получения скорости при **равноускоренном движении**.

```
V(текущая) = V(начальная) + G * t
```

G равна 9.81 м/c^2 т.е. наша скорость изменяется на -9.81 м/c по y за 1 секунду, так как dT как правило очень редко равна ровно 1 сек надо G * dT что бы получить дельта ускорение (dG) в данный момент времени.

```
V(текущая) = V(начальная) + dG * t
```

В моем случаем начальная скорость равна нулю по всем осям, значит

```
V(текущая) = dG * t
```

И чтобы получить скорость надо умножить dG на t, а t у нас равна dT значит можно записать формулу так

```
V(текущая) = G * dT * dT = G * dT^2
```

Вот и ответ